# is it possible to have multiple control-group in one row with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for creating a simple webpage. When I create a form containing some personal information, like first name, last name, email address, etc. Sometimes I prefer to make 2 control group (first name label & input field, and last name label & input field) in the same row. How can I achieve it ? It's not evident to do it in the **Horizontal-form**. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with horizontal form, you must use [`.form-inline` Twitter Bootstrap class](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms).

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="First name"/>
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Last name"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fq4wm/

Or, you can do that also in horizontal form, but you must to override many classes and properties, and I'll not recommend that. Better way is to use default Twitter Bootstrap classes for this stuff.

EDIT: You can combine horizontal and inline classes inside one form like this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="First name"/>
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Last name"/>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
           <div class="controls">
               <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fq4wm/6/

Comment: Thanks very much. I utilized **horizontal-form** in order to use its alignment property. But it seems I have to adopt the **form-inline**. BTW, may I use use one single **Submit** button for several forms (personal information, education, hobbies) in the same page, because for some form, I still prefer **horizontal-form** ?

Comment: You can do that with jQuery or new HTML5 [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form) atrribute. Easier solution is to set your own classes and align form elements by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class to make it an inline form:

```
<form class="form-inline">
   ...
</form>
```

Then it's easier to place fields in different rows and columns.